# Troubles with completely freeing a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I wrote a simple program in C to try to better understand how linked lists works but I have some difficulty on making my program free the resources used by my linked list.

I have implemented two functions (push and apppend) to add an element at the top of the list and another one to add an element at the bottom of it. I'm using a third function to free the space used by the linked list.

My program just fill the linked list with some value and then calls the function "destroy_list" to free the memory used by the linked list. But for some reason when I fill my list with append(), it looks like not all the memory that the list used is being freed.

Here is the code + some screenshot of the memory usage that I recorded while filling the linked list with push() and append():

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h> // used for Sleep(), use <unistd.h> for linux(?)

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    void* data;
    struct LinkedList* next;
} LinkedList;

void push(LinkedList** head, void* data_ptr)
{
    LinkedList* new = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    new->next = *head;
    new->data = data_ptr;

    *head = new;
}

void append(LinkedList* node, void* data_ptr)
{
    while (node->next != NULL)
        node = node->next;

    LinkedList* new = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    new->data = data_ptr;
    new->next = NULL;

    node->next = new;
}

void destroy_list(LinkedList** head)
{
    LinkedList* current_node = *head;
    LinkedList* next_node;

    while (current_node != NULL)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
    }
    *head = NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    // create initial head for the list
    LinkedList* list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    list->next = NULL;
    list->data = NULL;

    Sleep(1000); // added delay to better see the memory usage


    // trying to fill the list with both methods and compare the result of memory usage
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    {
        //append(list, NULL);

        push(&list, NULL);
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    // trying to free all struct LinkedList
    destroy_list(&list);

    system("Pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(I didn't put the malloc pointer checks in the code to make it a bit more clear.)

So when I try to fill the linked list with the function push(), I get kind of a normal behavior as almost all the memory before and after filling/freeing the list is almost the same (even though it is not exactly the same amount). And here is the screenshot I took:

[image: screenshot_push]

I added a delay before and after adding elements to the list for every tests so we can better see the differences.

So by filling the linked list with push() we get around ~900kb of memory usage at the end of the program.

Now here is the result of the exact same program but we use append() to fill the list :

[image: screenshot_append]

As we can see, it takes a bit more time to fill up the linked list as the append() method has to go through the entire list to add an element where the push() method don't. And at the end, the program did not freed nearly as much memory than with the previous method.

So I thought there should be something wrong with my append() function, maybe some sort of  memory leak where nodes in the linked list would escape the chain.

Then I did some more testing with the append() function and I noticed an even weirder behavior. When I try to increment a variable while looping in destroy_list() function and then print the result to see how many times the program calls free(), suddenly some more memory is being freed!

Here is the modified destroy_list() function:

```
void destroy_list(LinkedList** head)
{
    LinkedList* current_node = *head;
    LinkedList* next_node;

    int i = 0; // Added

    while (current_node != NULL)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
        i++; // Added
    }
    printf("%d\n", i); // Added
    *head = NULL;
}
```

And with this function and using the append() function to fill the list, we get this:

[image: screenshot_append_print]

I tried it a lot of times and I still get the same results for every screenshots i provided.

I really don't understand how it can be possible but I spent a lot of time on this and I really want to know what am I missing???

Comment: You seem to be testing with a very large number of elements. Do the errors appear when you test with half as many?

Comment: @Beta To answer your question, I did tried with half and even twice as many elements with the same results, but as user dbush said, the memory is correctly freed but it doesn't show instantly on the memory usage, but it looks like over time it tend to slowly decrease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the memory used by the process is not a good indicator of whether or not you are properly freeing all memory.  When a process gives memory back to the OS doesn't have to coincide with calls to `free`.

There are tools such as Valgrind on Linux that are made to specifically check for memory errors in running code.  When I ran this code through Valgrind, it came back clean.  There were no invalid memory accesses, and all allocated pointers were freed.

Comment: So, since the OS is responsible for allocating and freeing memory, could the graph above simply mean that the OS is taking its sweet time reclaiming some of the memory that is supposedly freed?

Comment: You are right, I made this code loop 10 times to allocate memory and then free it and it appears to stabilize around the same amount of memory every time (instead of just going up if some part of the memory was not being freed). 
Thanks a lot for your help, I'll mark this as solved! ( I spent way more time on this than i should have in the end :) )